# Can’t compile modules anymore after sdk updates to 7.0.2

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio, appcelerator-android

The latest updates of appcelerator to the newest SDK, cli, titanium studio, has now results in the failed built of every android modules I have created so far.

Below is the error -

```
Buildfile: /Users/Documents/sdk7module/android/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/Documents/sdk7module/android/build.xml:55: Cannot find /Users/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.0.2.GA/module/android/build.xml imported from /Users/Documents/sdk7module/android/build.xml

Total time: 448 milliseconds
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you update the `apiversion` in the manifest?

Comment: Yes I have updated to 4

Comment: Are you compiling via CLI? Please show us the command you are running.

Comment: I’m compiling via studio by clicking build.xml and “run as ant1”

Comment: ant is the old method to compile a module. Try to run `appc ti build -p android --build-only` in your project. Don't know about Studio :)

Comment: Using the command line to build the module, im getting this new error again -  
[ERROR] Failed to run ndk-build
[ERROR]   
[ERROR] /bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/ccache: No such file or directory
[ERROR] make: *** [/Users/Documents/customdm_1/android/build/generated/obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/custom.dm.one/custom.dm.one.Customdm1Module.o] Error 127

Answer (score 0):

After installing ccache, I was able to compile the module without any error.